# Cookie path always gets quoted using Apache Tomcat 7 but not Tomcat 9

Tags: apache, tomcat, servlets, cookies, servlet-3.0

I was implementing (using Apache Wicket 8.0.0-M6, JDK 1.8.0_20) a web application with some cookies running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.23 and all my cookies were being written with double quotes around their path whatever I did (no path ie default, /, /myapp/mysubdomain). This is preventing me from passing cookies betwseen my various webapps.

Eventually, I installed Apache Tomcat 9 (9.0.0.M26) and with JDK 1.8.0_141, this behaviour has gone away and the cookies are written correctly without the double quotes.

This is great and was without any config changes, but I am at a loss as to what in the upgrade has been responsible as I'd rather stick with Tomcat 7 for now if possible. Is it the change from the servlet 2 to 4 ? Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Did you refer to tomcat's migration guide? Here is tomcat's migration guide on cookies.

[Tomcat's migration guide on Cookies](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-9.html#Cookies)

It says,

> The default CookieProcessor is now the Rfc6265CookieProcessor. The
>   CookieProcessor is configurable per Context and the
>   LegacyCookieProcessor may be used to obtain the 8.0.x behaviour.

Try changing to LegacyCookieProcessor by adding following line in your  element.

```
<CookieProcessor className="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.LegacyCookieProcessor"/>
```

Comment: Yes I did read the migration guide but it's the other way round - I want the Tomcat 9 behaviour (it works) but ideally to have it in Tomcat 7, not to set Tomcat 9 to use the legacy cookie behaviour (which might not work).